# How separate words by excluding square brackets in C# using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a sentence like "Hello there [Gesture : 2.5] How are you" and I have separate the words by avoiding the whole square brackets. For example "Hello there How are you".

I tried to separate the words before the colon but that's not what I want. This is the code I've tried.

```
MatchCollection matches2 = Regex.Matches(avatarVM.AvatarText, @"([\w\s\[\]]+)");
```

The above code only separate the words before ":" which also include the opening square bracket and the word after. I want to avoid the whole square brackets

Comment: Can the "[Gesture : 2.5]" be at the start or the end of then line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the fragments before and after the brackets as separate entries in a collection:

```
Regex.Split(avatarVM.AvatarText, @"\[[^\]]+\]");
```

This will also work if there are multiple bracketed fragments in the string. You may want to `.Trim()` each entry.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps invert the problem and concentrate on what you want to remove rather than what you want to keep. For example, this will match the brackets and a space either side, and replace with a single space:

```
// Hello there How are you
var output = Regex.Replace("Hello there [Gesture : 2.5] How are you", @" \[.+\] ", " ");
```

If required, you could use a slightly more complicated version that can handle the square brackets not necessarily being surrounded by spaces, for example at the start or end of the input string:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(
            "Hello there How are you [Gesture : 2.5]", // input string
            @"[^\w]{0,1}\[.+\]([^\w]){0,1}", // our pattern to match the brackets and what's in between them
            "$1"); // replace with the first capture group - in this case the character that comes after
```

And if you wanted to you could use the overload of `Replace` taking a `MatchEvaluator` delegate to have more control over how it is replaced in the string and with what depending on what your needs are.

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = Regex.Replace("Hello there [Gesture : 2.5] How are you", @"\[.*?\] ", string.Empty);
```

Comment: please describe your answer with some content

Comment: Hi, 
First of all I would like to explain what my "\[.*?\]" regex will do \[ will look for square bracket .* will match zero to any number of characters  unit first \] occurs. and as I am using Regex.Replace of all similar occurrences will be replace by empty string